# Lead object marked as Private org wide default but SOQL returns Public for DefaultLeadAccess

Tags: apex, soql, api, leads, org-wide-defaults

I have modified the Org wide default for Lead to Private.

[image]

However, when I execute the SOQL to get org wide defaults - Select DefaultAccountAccess, DefaultLeadAccess From Organization, I am getting the Org wide default as Public. Note: I have waited for the background job to finish before querying.

[image]

The behavior however does changes to private within my org but, why is the SOQL returning it as public? Is there any other way to get org wide defaults?